# Download an image from its url and directly upload it to AWS

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, meteor, download, upload

I can't find a satisfying answer to my question. Given an image url, I want to download it (without saving it to the disk) and to immediately upload it to an AWS Bucket. Here is my code :

```
  self.downloadImage = function(url){
        let response = HTTP.get(url, {
            encoding:null // for binary
        })
        if (!response.headers['content-type'].split('/')[0] == 'image'){
            throw new Error("not an image")
        }
        return {
            data : response.content,
            contentType : response.headers['content-type']
        }
    }

    self.uploadImage = function(websiteName, imgUrl, callback){
        // we retrieve the image
        let image = downloadImage(imgUrl)
        let imageName = self.extractImageName(imgUrl)
        let filename = 'img/' +websiteName + "/" + imageName
        let newUrl = `https://s3.${Meteor.settings.AWS.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${Meteor.settings.S3.BUCKET_NAME}/${filename}`
        // makes the async function sync like
        let putObjectSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(s3Client.putObject, s3Client)
        try{
            let res = putObjectSync({
                Body: image.data,
                ContentType : image.contentType,
                ContentEncoding: 'base64',
                Key: filename,
                ACL:'public-read',
                Bucket: Meteor.settings.S3.BUCKET_NAME
            })
            return newUrl
        } catch(e) {
            return null
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, except that the image seems corrupted. So far I tried :

- to use `aldeed:http`, in order to set the encoding to `null` when downloading, which seems a good strategy for images
- not to use it and to pass the text content of the response directly as the upload body
- to add base64 encoding in aws

Still corrupted. I feel very close to the solution, as the image as the correct type and file size, but still won't print in the browser or on my computer. Any idea about how to correctly encode/retrieve the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the answer by myself :

`aldeed:meteor` allow to add a `responseType` parameter to the `get` request. We simply need to set this option to `buffer`, so that we get the data as a buffer. Then we simply give this buffer, with no transformation, as the `Body` of the upload function.